# How can I write a bootable iso to a partition instead of a drive, keeping the OS inside intact

Tags: linux, boot, usb, partitioning

I had a USB drive I used for all of my bootable isos (through Ventoy), but the drive seems to have failed,
and now any OS just doesn't see it as a drive. I have two other USBs, but both of them are used for Puppy Linux (one of them is also used as a data USB). Is there any way I can use one of them as a bootable USB, so I can reinstall the OS on it? It is corrupted, and I need to reinstall it somehow. Do I have any options?

Comment: Your title and question body are two different questions. The answer to 1st one is "no", and the 2nd one "maybe, but it's not worth the effort".

Comment: Are you asking how to How to *Install Multiple Bootable Operating Systems on a USB Stick*? See https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-multiple-bootable-operating-systems-on-one-usb-stick/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I know how to install two OSes to a USB drive. I am asking if it is possible to install Puppy Linux alongside a bootable iso without overriding its grub bootloader. Is there a way to make Puppy boot the iso from the boot selection? I also need to reinstall the existing OS on the drive. I think if I manage to boot into the iso, I am gonna be able to reinstall the OS, but it is not gonna work a second time. Basically the question in the title was a little more generic, but I just want to reinstall Puppy from the same drive, because I don't have any more USBs.